# How to define the current users ID from MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

If your site enables the sign up of multiple users then the chances are they will be able to update, delete or view their information. Now, **how does one define the id of the current user for them to access only their information/mysql row?**

For example: If you take the db structure below and bob is online, how can I tell the page that bob is the current user and his id = "1" and it do this for every user that is online.

Example db structure:

```
ID |  name | Email 
 1 |  bob  | bob@example.com
 2 |  john | john@example.com
```

**please note these are depreciated functions**
This is my login script, which just sends me in a loop of redirects. This was written with depreciated functions, how can I update it to use PDO?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])!="")
{
    header("Location:login.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']);

    $email = trim($email);
    $upass = trim($upass);

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

    if($count == 1 && $row['user_pass']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else
    {
echo '<div class="invalid-message text-center">Email or password is  invalid</div>';   
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: No, not a homework question, will update the question.

Comment: Sessions are the right thing to look at here. The step you still miss is that you can store variables inside such a session that are persistent over multiple requests. So once you have authenticated a specific user and know his ID you can save that inside the session. That way you know the ID on each following request, as long as the session exists and is used.

Comment: @arkascha Yes! that's what i've been trying to do, but I just get a internal error. two seconds, i'll post my code

Comment: You are _not_ trying to define a session variable in that code. Please start by taking a look at the documentation of php sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php Note: you _always_ should start with a look into the documentation of the tools you use if you have a question. It actually comes with good examples, for example here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: @arkascha that example gives the new user an ID doesn't fetch it from the db.

Comment: That does not make any difference. An ID is an ID, it is just a numeric value. It is totally irrelevant where it "comes" from. Your question is about how to store an ID in a session in a persistent manner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to approach this question from a different perspecitve - ratherthan simply saying there is a user with an id and a name, you need to back it up a couple of steps to think about how that user got that id and how did he/she log in.

You need to create a login page that will take the name / password and check it against the stored data in the database and if it is correct - allow the user to proceed with their use of the page. If it is not correct - you need to allow them to reenter the details (if they mis-typed the p/w for example) or to sign up if they do not have an account (and therefore no id).

Note that the password MUST NOT be stored as plain text in the DB and should be hashed (for example with SHA 256 encryption) and salted and it is this hashed and salted version of the P/W that you check upon login.

It is upon the successful login that you start the session and assign the database row of content related to that signed in user to the new session and it is from that session that the id and name will then be used from the session_start() as i have it here.

So in summary- when they log in, assuming that the login is correct, you then assign the details to the session and include session_start() to every page that you want included in the session, you can then reference the user by that $userID or $userName.

once you get your session, you can use something like this to identify the name and id of the user, which will be available on every page that you have session_start():

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user']) )
    {
        $userID=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $userName=$_SESSION['user']['name'];
    }....
```

When the user wants to logout or you want to delete the session details related to that user's activity, you can use :

```
unset($_SESSION['user']);
```

and then you can redirect them to another page

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: what is this part referring to?  ['user']['id'] or ['user']['name']

Comment: this is the nomenclature for referring to a session called "user" - as i described in my edited thesis of an answer - you create a session (in this case called "user") when the user logs in - please read my full answer to get a concept of the process and as described above - read the documentaton for sessions and their use...